# Should I merge an object model with a sprite or make a refernce

Tags: flash

I'm making a game where I have must have some objects like weapons and characters, which I in the end would like to get visual as a sprite or movieclip

Should I write the logic for the objects in several classes and then make a reference to the object in a sprite class like the following :

```
public class WeaponModel
{

    public damage:Int = 8;

    public function Weapon(){
        //Do the constructor code
    }

    public function get damage():int{
        return this.damage;
    }
}

public class WeaponSprite extends Sprite
{

    var weaponModel:WeaponModel;

    public function WeaponSprite(weaponModel:WeaponModel){
        this.weaponModel = weaponModel;
    }
public function get weaponModel():WeaponModel{
        return this._weaponModel;
    }
}
```

And then when I need to do damage just call the WeaponSprite's method weaponModel() when I need to acces the methods or should I just merge the two together into one class.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid passing a reference to the model to a view. A more decoupled approach would be to pass a model id to the view. The provide access to the model id through a getter. In general you want to keep knowledge of models out of views and knowledge of views out of models.

Below is an example of how a controller class might manage the relationship between views and models.

```
class View
{
   public function View( modelId:int )
   {
      this._id = modelId;
   }

   public function get modelId():int { return this._id; }

   protected function doSomething():void 
   {
        dispatchEvent( new Event(Event.DOING_SOMETHING) );
   }
}

class Controller 
{
    function init()
    {
        for each( model in models )
        {
            var view = new View( model.id );
            view.addEventListener( Event.DOING_SOMETHING, onViewDoingSomething );
        }
    }

    protected function onViewDoingSomething( event:Event ):void 
    {
       if( event.target is View )
       var view:View = event.target as View;
       // -- do something with view.modelId here
    }
}
```

Another thing to consider is how large of an application you are building and how many people will be working on it. When building a quick prototype, you may not be concerned with following strict OOP patterns. However, the larger and more complex a project gets, the more likely it is that a framework or specific design patterns will be of value to you.

If you are interested in learning a framework that facilitates consistent and flexible designs, [consider looking at Robot Legs](http://www.robotlegs.org/).

Comment: What do you mean by passing a model id to the view. What would I get out of that? I'm not planning on using MVC for this game. I simply can't find a decent tutorial on how I could use MVC for a game in flash.

Comment: MVC is a good pattern to use for the game menu and everything *but the game itself*. So it's probably not a bad idea to look at RobotLegs, which is a great framework.